# How can I configure details of an iFrame print such as title, etc

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

i need to print a screenshot from within a phaser 3 game and I achieved that with a dynamically created iframe from within the games snapshot function:

```
this.game.renderer.snapshot(function(image){
    var printframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    printframe.style.display = "none";
    printframe.setAttribute("id","printframe");
    printframe.setAttribute("name","printframe");
    document.body.appendChild(printframe);
    setTimeout(function(){
        printframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML='<img src="'+image.src+'">';
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.frames["printframe"].print(); 
        }, 500);
},500)
```

})

Now this works, but I have "about:blank", a page number and a date / time printed as well. 
How can I configure this a bit more granularly?

thanks!

Comment: Well since the docs: [<iframe>: The Inline Frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), tell us that _"The HTML Inline Frame element (<iframe>) represents a nested browsing context, embedding another HTML page into the current one."_. How about making the contents of the iframe a fully qualified HTML document, like it's supposed to be?

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean add a proper print style sheet?
The about:blank does come from the document.url, which is read only.

Comment: Anyways: The items I mentioned are controlled by the users browser. 
So no way to configure that from within JS.